# 2 dimensional array using user prompt()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```js
var playerinfo = [
    ["Anisul", 122],
    ["Rahim", 433],
    ["Kabir Singh", 788],
    ["Munna", 56],
    ["Rasel", 120]
];

function highestRunScorer(playerinfo) {
    var highScorer = playerinfo[0][0];
    var highScore = playerinfo[0][1];
    for (var x = 1; x < playerinfo.length; x++) {
        if (highScore < playerinfo[x][1]) {
            highScore = playerinfo[x][1];
            highScorer = playerinfo[x][0];
        }
    }
    return highScorer;
}

var names = highestRunScorer(playerinfo);
console.log(names);
```

now I am wondering how I can take the user input to create this 2d array and solve this in a real-world way.

I have tried searching how I can create a 2d array using prompt. But no luck so far. Hence posting here. I am new to Javascript by the way.

Comment: *" and solve this in a real-world way"* well real-world ways don't use prompt.

Comment: For the time being, let's assume it does because I will get to learn it.

Comment: Then please show us your attempt at using `prompt` so we can help you see the mistake

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(playerinfo))` then prompt your users to enter in that format (`[]` brackets, `,` commas and `"` quotes) then `let info = JSON.parse(prompt("Enter player info"))`

Comment: Otherwise you can prompt in *any* format you like, eg "Name1:122,Name2:433" and then use js to split on comma then each value split on ":" (and probably trim as well)( to get the expected array - much easier for the user than entering in strict json format, but more code for you.   If your names *might* have commas, then use a different separator, pipe `|` is quite common as that doesn't tend to appear in names.   *"real-world way"* would *sanitise* (validate) any user input.

Comment: Letting a user input encoded JSON through a `prompt` sound like really bad practice, even just to learn. I'd make 2 inputs, for a name and the score with a `+` button that will add 2 more inputs. Then a button `calculate` that will read all those `input`'s and find the largest.

Comment: I can't think of a reason to bother learning to use `prompt()`, even morbid curiosity has - or should have - its limits. The only benefit you'll take from the experience is that it's a terrible idea, a waste of precious time, unattractive, inconsistent from one browser to the next, unable to styled, it's not guaranteed to work, and probably several other reasons it should never be used. See the documentation on MDN: [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Comment: @0stone0 totally agree - and certainly wouldn't be "real-world"

Comment: "*using prompt*" - as a *single* (one-off) prompt - ie all the values at once - or using multiple prompts - ie one row at a time?  (or one-row-col at a time as per an answer below)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done here is use prompt capture user input and parseInt to parse the number by doing so take rows and columns which I need to initialize the multidimensional array. Once after getting the numbers of multi dimensional array. Another two for-loops to iterate over row and colums to find the highest number.

You can do it using the below code :

```js
function findHighestValueInArray() {
    // Taking input for the number of rows and columns
    const numRows = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of rows:"));
    const numCols = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of columns:"));

    // Initializing a two-dimensional array
    const matrix = [];

    // Taking input for each element in the array
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        const row = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            const userInput = prompt(`Enter element at position (${i + 1},${j + 1}):`);
            // Parsing the input to check if it's an integer
            const element = parseInt(userInput);

            // Adding the element to the row
            row.push(isNaN(element) ? userInput : element);
        }
        // Adding the row to the matrix
        matrix.push(row);
    }

    // Finding the highest value in the array
    let highestValue = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            // Check if the element is an integer
            if (typeof matrix[row][col] === 'number') {
                // Update highestValue if the current element is greater
                highestValue = Math.max(highestValue, matrix[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Returning the highest value
    return highestValue;
}

// Example usage:
const result = findHighestValueInArray();
console.log('The highest value is:', result);
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Okay I will explain

Comment: Seems overly complicated / confusing UX to prompt for rows/columns first then prompt the user for a "matrix" one cell at a time.